# Export the result of sql statement in xml format

Tags: xml, oracle

I need to export the result in xml format, here below is the code :

```
DECLARE
      XmlFic  Utl_File.File_Type;
      XmlData CLOB;
      Fin     BOOLEAN := TRUE;
    BEGIN
       XmlData := DBMS_XMLQuery.GetXML ('SELECT * FROM employees');
       XmlFic := Utl_File.FOpen ('C:\TMP\XML', 'TEST.xml', 'W');
       WHILE FIN LOOP
          Utl_File.Put (XmlFic, SUBSTR (XmlData, 1, 32767));
          IF LENGTH (XmlData) > 32767 THEN
             XmlData :=  SUBSTR (XmlData, 32768);
          ELSE
             FIN := FALSE;
          END IF;
       END LOOP;
       Utl_File.FClose (XmlFic);
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SUBSTR (SQLERRM,1,255));
          Utl_File.FClose (XmlFic);
    END;
```

I get the following error :

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 11:
>   PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_FILE' MUST BE DECLARED
>   PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_XMLQUERY.GETXML' MUST BE DECLARED

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Will it work if you use SYS.DBMS_XMLQUERY instead of only DBMS_XMLQUERY? If that works there is no synonym created (or even the original is deleted).

Source: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2237396